Pythonic way to obtain ipmitool command provides incomplete output
I have been struggling with this simple problem and I dont seem to find a way around it.
I am trying to fetch the output of ipmitool command's output of fru with -v flag, using python code.
Output when executing ipmitool binary:
root@linux# ipmitool fru print 1 -v 2> /dev/null
 Product Manufacturer  : Artesyn
 Product Name          : CSU2400AP-3-400
 Product Part Number   : aa-bbbb-XX
 Product Version       :
 Product Serial        : RxxyyaabbzzKZ
 Power Supply Record
  Capacity                   : 2400 W
  Peak VA                    : 2620 VA
  Inrush Current             : 35 A
  Inrush Interval            : 255 ms
  Input Voltage Range 1      : 180-240 V
  Input Voltage Range 2      : 0-0 V
  Input Frequency Range      : 0-60 Hz
  A/C Dropout Tolerance      : 1 ms
  Flags                      : 'Predictive fail' 'Power factor correction' 'Hot swap' 'Failure on pin assertion'
  Peak capacity              : 2732 W
  Peak capacity holdup       : 15 s
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

root@linux# echo $?
139


What seems to be a simple task of writing python code to parse this output, for whatever reason, I am not getting the complete output.
Python Code snippet:
    def exec_ipmitool_cmd(self, cmd):
        try:
            logthis("Executing raw ipmi cmd: {}".format(cmd))
            child = subprocess.Popen(
                cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            
            out, err = child.communicate()
            logthis("cmd status: {}".format(child.returncode))
            if out:
                logthis("Cmd output: ")
                for l in out.decode('utf-8').split('\n'):
                    if l:
                        logthis(l)
            if err:
                logthis("ipmi_err: {}".format(err.strip()))
            ...

cmd = ['ipmitool', 'fru', 'print', '1', '-v', '2>', '/dev/null']
Output when running ipmitool binary through python code:
When ran independently the output seem to contain all the information I needed, but when ran with python code, the same cmd did not provide the complete info.
Logs below. This puzzles me.
2024-04-08 09:37:39,370 Executing raw ipmi cmd: ['ipmitool', 'fru', 'print', '1', '-v', '2>', '/dev/null']
2024-04-08 09:37:39,435 cmd status: -11
2024-04-08 09:37:39,435 ipmi_err: b'Loading IANA PEN Registry...\nRunning Get VSO Capabilities my_addr 0x20, transit 0, target 0\nInvalid completion code
received: Invalid command\nDiscovered IPMB address 0x0'

Quick search on this error gave reference to this which does not seem to be a problem. But still did not explain on what happened to the rest of the output.
I am not able to get the complete output at all starting from Product Manufacturer..
TIA
